# Как управлять значением define средствами autotools?

Tags: c, компиляция, autoconf, autotools

Допустим, я хочу написать следующую программу:

hello.h:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define STR "some string like Hello World"
```

hello.c:

```
#include <hello.h>

int main()
{
    printf(STR);
    return 0;
}
```

И теперь, когда я буду собирать эту программу с помощью autotools, я хочу управлять значением этой строки (той, что в define). Т.е. я хочу прописать некую переменную в configure.ac, которая протянется через Makefile до этого хидера.
Как этого можно добиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это не сложно:

configure.ac

```
MY_ENABLE="1"
MY_STRING="some string like Hello World from configure"

AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([HAVE_MY_ENABLE], [$MY_ENABLE], ["enable my variable"])
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([HAVE_MY_STRING], ["$MY_STRING"], ["my string"])
```

hello.h:

```
// производит autotools && configure в корневой папке проекта,
// там же где живет и configure,
// если в configure.ac не указан другой путь или имя,
// задаеться с помощью дерективы AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h]).
#include "config.h"

#if defined(HAVE_MY_ENABLE)
#define STR HAVE_MY_STRING
#else
#define STR "-empty-"
#endif
```

если есть желание иметь эту переменную в Makefile(.am,.in):

configure.ac

```
AC_SUBST([MY_ENABLE])
```

если необходимо в Makefile(.am,.in) иметь Conditional переменную для выполнения условий, то:

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_COND_MY_ENABLE], [test "$MY_ENABLE" == "1"])
```

Makefile.am:

```
AM_MY_ENABLE = @MY_ENABLE@

if HAVE_COND_MY_ENABLE
  myprog_SOURCES += \
    $(top_srcdir)/src/path/my-include-code.c
endif
```

добавил пример с передачей строки из configure

Comment: Либо я здесь чего-то не понял, либо вы меня. Мне нужно прописать значение строки, которую я хочу выводить на экран в configure.ac, и чтобы после autoreconf,configure она попала в hello.h (причем этот хидер вообще уже написан, там есть еще много всякого, просто я упростил тут все для примера). Из вашего же примера, если я правильно понял, я могу управлять тем, какое из двух значений примет строка.

Comment: посмотрите, речь об этом ?

Comment: Ну, почти. Мне только нужно, чтобы hello.h содержал еще много всякой заранее описанной штуки, необходимой для работы программы. Кажется, мне нужно исходный hello.h переименовать в hello.h.in, прописать его в configure.ac, и потом сгенерируется тот hello.h, который нужен мне.

Comment: Ну, и немного избыточно выглядит. Обязателен ли MY_ENABLE="1", если известно, что он всегда должен быть включен?

Comment: Условие логическое. Это пример, поменяйте как вам будет удобнее, в любом случае дефайн этой строки находиться в config.h . Достаточно подключить config.h к вашему исходнику hello.c